# How to write a fraction in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm making a small application to help kids to learn mathematics for kids.

However, I don't know how to write a fraction in SwiftUI ?

I would like something like this : <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Explain more, please

Comment: A good question but unfortunately without a good answer

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Now completely dynamic with font scaling supported, no layout hardcodes.

Main part:

```
    ZStack {
        Text("\(numerator) ")
            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center,
                            computeValue: { d in d[.bottom] })
            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center,
                            computeValue: { d in d[.trailing] })

        Text("\u{2215}").font(.system(size: scale))

        Text(" \(denominator)")
            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center,
                            computeValue: { d in d[.top] })
            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center,
                            computeValue: { d in d[.leading] })
    }
```

[Test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestNumericFractionByLayout.swift)

#### Original

Hope the following will be helpful. Of course you can tune parameters as you wish.

Demo:

[image: SwiftUI fraction view]

Approach code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FractionView: View {
    var numerator: String
    var denominator: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(numerator)")
                .offset(x: 4, y: 0)
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center,
                                computeValue: { d in d[.bottom] })
            Text("∕").font(.system(size: 32))
            Text("\(denominator)")
                .offset(x: -4, y: 0)
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center,
                                computeValue: { d in d[.top] })
        }
    }
}

struct TestFraction: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            FractionView(numerator: "1", denominator: "2")
            FractionView(numerator: "5", denominator: "7")
            FractionView(numerator: "11", denominator: "19")
            FractionView(numerator: "31", denominator: "9")
        }
    }
}

struct TestFraction_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestFraction()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across an approach that might be more flexible than the currently proposed solution (not needing adaptation for different font sizes or styles).

Use the Unicode symbols for superscript and subscript numbers in combination with the Unicode fraction slash. A very simple solution could be:

```
Text("\u{2077}\u{2044}\u{2081}\u{2081}") // --> returns ⁷⁄₁₁
```

There is an interesting article that discusses this approach further: https://coderexmachina.medium.com/displaying-mathematical-fractions-in-swiftui-6a4dd625d842